# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not “int”) to list. Help Needed

Tags: python, python-3.x

This seems basic but have been giving me some headache. I have a CSV file and a function that calculates the UTM zone from the lat and long field. I keep getting this error. I am not sure what i am doing wrong. The Python function works when I pass a random lat and long values to the call function. But it gives an error, shown at the bottom, when I try to calculate from the CSV file in Pandas.

The field has 6 header column: Date | AAA | BBB | Lat | Long | Distance

Here is my code:

```
path2 = (r'C:\Users\newsample.csv')
openfile2 = pd.read_csv(path2, header='infer')

# Convert Long and Lat rows to list
lon = (list(openfile2['Long']))
lat = (list(openfile2['Lat']))
latitude = []
longitude = []

for la in lat:
    la = pd.to_numeric(openfile2['Lat'])
    latitude.append(la)

for lo in lon:
    lo = pd.to_numeric(openfile2['Long'])
    latitude.append(lo)

# compute UTM zone for the rows
def get_zone(lat, lon):
    zone = int((lon + 186) / 6)
    if lat >= 56.0 and lat < 64.0 and lon >= 3.0 and lon < 12.0:
        zone = 32
    if lat >= 72.0 and lat < 84.0:
        if lon >= 0.0 and lon < 9.0:
            zone = 31
        elif lon >= 9.0 and lon < 21.0:
            zone = 33
        elif lon >= 21.0 and lon < 33.0:
            zone = 35
        elif lon >= 33.0 and lon < 42.0:
            zone = 37
    if lat > 0:
        cs = "EPSG::326" + str(zone)
    else:
        cs = "EPSG::327" + str(zone)
    return cs

# Call function
newfile = get_zone(latitude, longitude)
print(newfile)
```

I get a **TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list**

Comment: Please format your question so it is readable.

Comment: Please provide the full `Traceback` so we can easily see which line is problematic in your code.

Comment: I'm guessing it's this line: `zone = int((lon + 186) / 6) ` -- `lon` is a list correct?

Comment: change the name of the variables in this call `def get_zone(lat, lon):` `lon` and `lat` are list no?

Comment: @nicoco, here is the full trace error "<ipython-input-243-4cb992596cdc> in get_zone(lat, lon)
     22 #compute UTM zone for the rows
     23 def get_zone(lat, lon):
---> 24    zone = int((lon + 186) / 6)
     25    if lat >= 56.0 and lat < 64.0 and lon >= 3.0 and lon < 12.0:
     26        zone = 32

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: @Stringz as a general rule, please edit your question instead of replying in comment. Anyway, the problematic line has been identified by others.

Comment: Dont forget to upvote answers that helped you and accept the one which addresses your question most accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is at `zone = int((lon + 186) / 6)`

You are trying to convert a list of integers into a single integer.

`int()` takes one argument, and its not a list.

> Illustration

```
li1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
zone = int((li1 + 186) / 6)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

```
>>help(int)
```

..

```
class int(object)
 |  int(x=0) -> integer
 |  int(x, base=10) -> integer
 |  
 |  Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
 |  are given.  If x is a number, return x.__int__().  For floating point
 |  numbers, this truncates towards zero.
 |  
 |  If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
 |  bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the
 |  given base.  The literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded
 |  by whitespace.  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.
 |  Base 0 means to interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.
```

> Update
>   for converting two individual lists into one single list of tuples

```
z = zip(li1,li2)
latLong = list(z)
```

Then run `get_zone` on all:

```
for x,y in latLong:
    cal_zone = get_zone(x,y)
    print(cal_zone)
```

Comment: So how do i covert my list of intergers to a single int or vise-versa

Comment: That depends on what logic you intend to use. Do you want to get **summation** of all elements of list or few elements ? or specific indices like 0th? or even **average** of all lattitudes?

Comment: I want each rows of lat and long to have their own utm values from the function

Comment: in that case call `get_zone()` for all the values with a for loop

Comment: i used a loop, no solution. TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list. Can you show me an example with the code above?

Comment: updated the answer. Please update the question asking your current requirement, that would help fellow stackoverflow users

Comment: thanks so much, you made it look so simple. Hope to be like you soon. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your list to string and join it then convert result to int for `zone = int((lon + 186) / 6)`   to work

```
numList = [1,2,3,4,5]

num = int(''.join(map(str,numList)))

print(num)

#output
>>12345
```

Update:
If you need to sum up all values from the list then use `sum(map(float,numList))` instead of `int(''.join(map(str,numList)))` but i get the feeling that you want to access each item in the list individually in which case a list comprehension or some generator would be in place.

Update2:
    Your list contains strings with `\n` characters so you need to strip these by calling `strip()` function on all items you append to list and then perform your list operation as below.

```
numList = ['1.2','3.4','4.5']

for item in numList:
    item = (float(item) + 187) / 6    # Do something with each item
    print(item)
```

Comment: Ok so your list contains float values not ints. In this case you need to tell me what output do you expect there. Do you need to sum up your list values?

Comment: I plan to add a new field in a new csv file and update each lat and long rows with the new calculated UTM

Comment: Oh i see .. so you need to access each value of a list and perform that operation on it.

Comment: Another thing to notice is that you should use `latitude.append(la.strip())` and the same for longtitude to get rid of `\n` new line character from the list.